# Copy resources efficiently with the command line into another project

Tags: android, bash, shell, command-line

Occasionally, I need to move android resources from one project into another.  For example, [Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/) outputs a .zip file that when extracted yields a res folder with the usual Android directory structure.

```
res/ 
  - drawable-ldpi/
  - drawable-mdpi/
  - drawable-hdpi/
  - drawable-xhdpi
```

Usually, a different sized resource is placed in each directory with the same name.  So, button.png would exist in drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, and drawable-xhdpi. What command or script could be used to copy or move the outputted drawable folders into my project at once without copying over the entire res directory and overwritten other files?

Comment: A 'mv' should do the trick: mv res/* {your_project}/res/, shouldn't it?

Comment: Does mv overwrite things that might already be in the directory?

Comment: Yes, but you can protect against that with `mv -i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mv` does not move directories but its content.
You should use

```
 $ cd orig
 $ tar cf - res | (cd dest; tar xkf -)
```

The remove what you don't want from **orig**.